# Can you help me with a function with cos and radians?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have this function: $$d(n)=15-2,5\cdot\cos\left(\pi\frac{n-31}{360}\right).$$ This function talks about the difference between  when day start and day over. When I change $n$ for $5$  result for me is $12{,}5$. When I change for $10$ result is $12{,}5$. When I go insert the function on my calculator the function create one graph straight.

And the exercise say for find the day when the time between day start and day over is $12{,}33$ like $12$ hours and $33$ minutes? I guess it's impossible so I need help!

Arguments on cos are express by radians i don't know if this can make a change on result!

Comment: Do you mean the function $d(n) = 15 - 2.5cos\left(\pi\,\frac{n-31}{360}\right)$?  If so, it's not constant.  Sure it varies slowly for modest changes in n...after all you are dividing by 360 in there!  But perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: yes , but always   i try change the n for other number i receive 12,5 result

Comment: but  is (πn−31) not like you represent

Comment: What is $n$ supposed to be? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: one day and D represent the time between the day start and the day start and day over

Comment: 12 hours 33 minutes is 12.55 hours in decimal; your formula gives _decimal_ hours, not sexagesimal hours (for instance, 12:33).  14:15 hours is 14.25 hours in decimal, and so on.  So you're actually pretty near the days you're looking for.  (And there are _two_ days where the length of daylight is 12.55 hours.)

Comment: Also, your graph _is_ going to be rather flat.  The period of the cycle is 360 days (the way this function is defined) and the amplitude (amount of variation) is not all that large, so you have to compress the horizontal scale quite a bit to see the value change much.

Comment: $d(n)$ is between $12.5$ and $17.5$ no matter what you choose $n$. I can't figure what your function represents.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the minimum value of the given sinusoidal function is $12.5$ days, and so it will never reach $12.33$ days. If you really want it to be $12$ hours and $33$ minutes, then converting units yields $12 + \frac{33}{60} = 12.55$ days, which is attainable. Two solutions are found as follows:
\begin{align*}
12.55 &= 15 - 2.5 \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{360}(n - 31)) \\
0.98 &= \cos(\tfrac{\pi}{360}(n - 31)) \\
\tfrac{\pi}{360}(n - 31) &= \arccos(0.98), 2\pi - \arccos(0.98) \\
n &= \tfrac{360}{\pi}\arccos(0.98) + 31, \tfrac{360}{\pi}(2\pi - \arccos(0.98)) + 31 \\
n &= 53.9567\ldots, 728.043\ldots
\end{align*}
But since the period is $\frac{2\pi}{\pi/360} = 720$, we can subtract a period from the second solution so that our two smallest positive solutions are:
$$
n = 8.04331\ldots, 53.9567\ldots
$$

Comment: The function represents hours of daylight over the course of a year at some specific latitude.  The period should really be 365 (days), but I assumed the person posing the problem was keeping it simpler for students.  The minimum at 12.5 hours should occur at winter solstice, but so it's not clear what  $ \ n \ = \ 0 \ $ represents here.